# R lme4 interpret MLM confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I'm using the lme4 package in R to run a multilevel model and to calculate confidence intervals:

```
model <- lmer(cadence ~ fd + height + (1+fd|id), data=df, 
                        REML=FALSE)

confint.merMod(model, method = "boot", boot.type = "perc", 
               nsim = 500, oldNames = FALSE)
```

I'm trying to understand what the output is showing me:

```
                             2.5 %      97.5 %
sd_(Intercept)|id      0.590230649  0.92396467
cor_fd.(Intercept)|id -0.999990953  1.00000000
sd_fd|id               0.003862849  0.10373958
sigma                  0.295910811  0.35343478
(Intercept)           -0.247134271  0.27844609
fd                    -0.038814987  0.04487689
height                -0.795405634 -0.28511542
```

The `fd` and `height` rows are showing my the .95CI around the respective regression coefficient (fixed effects)

The ones I'm mainly struggling with are `sd_(Intercept)|id`, `cor_fd.(Intercept)|id`, and `sd_fd|id`. What do they represent?

My best guess is that `sd_(Intercept)|id` is the CI around the standard deviation of intercept values. If so, then what does `sigma` represent?

`sd_fd|id` Im guessing is the SD of all the estimated slope values for each `id`

Finally, I'm not sure what `cor_fd.(Intercept)|id` is meant to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I fit an example model using the built-in [sleepstudy dataset](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/sleepstudy.html).

```
(fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy))
#Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
#   Data: sleepstudy
#REML criterion at convergence: 1743.628
#Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr
# Subject  (Intercept) 24.740       
#          Days         5.922   0.07
# Residual             25.592       
#Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
#Fixed Effects:
#(Intercept)         Days  
#     251.41        10.47
```

These are the confidence intervals (on the right, I list what each interval pertains to):

```
confint.merMod(fm1, method = "boot", boot.type = "perc", nsim = 500, oldNames = F)
#Computing bootstrap confidence intervals ...
#                                   2.5 %      97.5 %
#sd_(Intercept)|Subject        13.1760846  35.3154169 --> random intercept SD
#cor_Days.(Intercept)|Subject  -0.5739618   0.9384943 --> correlation between random intercept and random slope
#sd_Days|Subject                3.2990883   8.1234449 --> random slope SD
#sigma                         22.6901363  28.3167813 --> residual SD
#(Intercept)                  237.9993456 265.4882890 --> fixed intercept
#Days                           7.1383003  13.6773242 --> fixed slope
```

Comment: I added some text to introduce what you're doing here, & critically, to identify where the explanation is in your post. Feel free to edit this to put something more extensive of your own choosing.